# JSF f:selectItems value partially bold

Tags: jsf, facelets, selectmanycheckbox

This is my checkboxes:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox style="font-size: 8pt; text-align: left" id="inputGroupIDBoxes" layout="pageDirection" value="#{pc_DesignersInterface.selectedInputGroupIDs}" rendered="#{pc_DesignersInterface.showInputGroup}">                 
    <f:selectItems value="#{pc_DesignersInterface.inputGroupIDs}" />                
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

and this is my backbean:

```
inputGroupIDs.add(new SelectItem(st.nextToken().trim(),"<b>--</b>" + GrpFieldIds.get(g).trim()));
```

but I don't get bold `--` in the check box.  What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - this is my checkboxes: <h:selectManyCheckbox style="font-size: 8pt; text-align: left" id="inputGroupIDBoxes" layout="pageDirection" value="#{pc_DesignersInterface.selectedInputGroupIDs}" rendered="#{pc_DesignersInterface.showInputGroup}">      
     <f:selectItems value="#{pc_DesignersInterface.inputGroupIDs}" />    
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `escape` of the `SelectItem` from its constructor:

```
new SelectItem(st.nextToken().trim(),"<b>--</b>" + GrpFieldIds.get(g).trim(), 
    null, false, true)
```

here its signature `new SelectItem(value, label, description, disabled, escape)`